# ccTouchesMoved [touches anyObject] confusion?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Ok so I am still kind of trying to get my bearings in Objective-C and I thought I had it down but now I came across this method.  So there are is something that confuses me that I would like a detailed explanation on if possible.

The first line: 'UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];', now to my understanding anyObject is a hashtable?  But how can you define it in this context?  I don't get where its defined at, I know it belongs to NSSet, but I am confused with the scope in this context...

```
- (BOOL)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];

    point =  [[Director sharedDirector] convertCoordinate: point];
    NSLog(@"ccTouchesMoved x=%f y=%f", point.x, point.y);
    return YES;

}
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`anyObject` in this case is a method on `NSSet`. Why do think it is a hashtable?
It simply returns an object from set - any object.

`[touches anyObject]`

invokes `anyObject` method on `touches` object (e.g. a method call in other languages) and it returns an object from the set.

```
NSTouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
```

`touch` is a pointer to one of the objects stored in `touches` (`NSSet`).

From Cocoa reference:

> anyObject Returns one of the objects
>   in the receiver, or nil if the
>   receiver contains no objects.
>
> `- (id)anyObject`
>
> Return Value One of the objects in the
>   receiver, or nil if the receiver
>   contains no objects. The object
>   returned is chosen at the receiver’s
>   convenience—the selection is not
>   guaranteed to be random.

Answer (score 1):

anyObject is actually a property. So you can use:

```
NSTouch * touch = touches.anyObject;
```

It will work the same.